# An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I have created a dataframe with 'Name and Age' as columns. Also, I have created two UDFs: one to convert the string to 'Title Case' and another to return the length of the string.**

**but, constantly an exception is thrown by UDF.'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'**

**how to rectify this?**

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test app").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=(["aaaaa bbbb cccc",23],["dddd eeee ffff",27]),schema=("Name","Age"))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("emp")

@udf(returnType = StringType())
def demoFunc(str):
    finalStr = ""
    newStr = str.split(" ")
    for i in newStr:
        finalStr = finalStr + i[0:1].upper() + i[1:len(i)] + " "
    return finalStr

spark.udf.register("initCap",demoFunc)
spark.udf.register("length",lambda z : len(z),IntegerType())

spark.sql("""select initCap(Name) from emp""").show()
spark.sql("""select length(Name) from emp""").show()
```

[exception thrown by UDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13tWo.png)

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why you chose to write your own version of the string method `title()`?

Comment: now I removed that. I just imported 'String' to test that package, no other reasons. just ignore that, thanks. (edited the code now)

Comment: Which version of Spark?

Comment: spark version 3.1.2